# SSRS Reporting multi value parameters

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a ssrs report, that gives me multiple product's price. My Parameter is not drill down, I have to type in the parameters(since I have large range of product number).

Now my questions is, how can i get the last entered product ( parameter) always appear at the bottom of the report ?. This would help me where to look the latest product in the report.For example I have product numbers like: 
abc-234,
abc-570,
ght-908,

Now what I want is that the latest entered product number which is ght-908 to appear at the bottom of the ssrs reports. Right now it gives me the report for the multiple product, but its all over the place and i have to squint my eyes and try to find out where my most recent entered product numbers (parameters) is. I have also tried to stop the parameters to being refreshed everytime i add a product number.

Comment: So just to confirm - user types in comma-separated list of parameters and you need to display last parameter at the bottom of every page below the data?

Comment: yes! that's exactly what i need to do. I am using a store procedure that joins a tvf delimitedsplit8k, which allows me to have a multiple parameters seperated by comma. I can keep on adding the parameters. I want the last added parameters to appear at the bottom of the reports. Thank you much appreciated for the time and effort..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your parameter name is `MyParameter`, in report designer (BIDS) just drop a textbox onto report below the data (e.g. Table) and put following expression into its value's formula:

```
=Parameters!MyParameter.Value.Split(",")(Parameters!MyParameter.Value.Split(",").Length - 1)
```

it will split the parameter list and grab the last value

**Update:** here is the screenshot with steps:

[image]

And here is the runtime result

[image]

Comment: you lost me there!! do you mean to say drop a text box below product number ( Which is my parameter)?? I am not so sure when you mean below the data.. I am sorry if i sound stupid..

Comment: I have attached a screenshot, does this make sense?

Comment: thats exactly what I had done earlier but it gives me error. If you notice that there is a red squiggly line underneath the split. Here is my expression which is based on your example, =Parameters!Product_Number.Value.Split(",")(Parameters!Product_Number.Value.Split(",").Length - 1)

Comment: Never mind that red line, it simple means it doesn't recognize it at design time. What happens when you actually run the report?

Comment: the reports gets generated and the text box where i had expression it gives out #Error. The report is not giving me the last product the way i intented it to. Thankx for the reply.

Comment: Please verify if the formula is entered correctly and correct parameter and data are used. I just verified it at runtime (see above screenshot) and it seems to work as designed.

Comment: Yuriy your logic works if i use the comma at the end of the product nubmer for example abc-123,zyg-789, ght-123 but if i do so I get the last intered product nubmer ONLY , what i want is i want all the product nubmer entered before as well but i want the last entered product nubmer ght-123 at the end..I hope its not too confusing.. thankx dude

Comment: It is a bit confusing. You mean you enter one parameter at a time (e.g.) "enter param 1 - run report", "enter param 2 -  run report" etc. and you want all parameters from multiple report runs accumulated together?

Comment: No I can enter as many product number as i want at a time, let say i entered 5 product number first time, and then again i intered one more product number so my final result should have 5 +1 product number with the last product number at the bottom row. righ now i get every thing i want, except I can't get the last entered product number at the bottom row.

Answer (score 0):

This expression works for me:

```
=Trim(Right(Parameters!Product_Number.Value
  , InStr(StrReverse(Parameters!Product_Number.Value), ",") - 1))
```

`Trim` might not be strictly necessary but is useful as it will work if the values are split with spaces as well as commas, or not.

For example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank Ian Preston for the input, but it's still not working. The report uses a stored proc which has a where condition like this:WHERE  (Product_Number IN (SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K] (@Product_Number, ','))) and the report is not a drop down, so I can type or paste the product number in the drop down space with out having to use the comma. This might make it more clear about my issues. thankx for the time and effort you guys are awesome..

Comment: I feel like both answers address the original question, so I'm not really sure what you're asking, sorry. I think maybe rethinking how the issue is described would be helpful.

Comment: Let me try this, I have a report that generates multiple product nubmer and the prices. my product numbers are like abc-123, xyg-908 trx-1255 and so on now what i want is If i entered abc-123 and xyg-908  i should be able to get both the product number and price but xyg-908 should be at the bottom and if i keep on adding other product number they should keep on appearing at the bottom of the rows. I hope this will help to make it clear.

Comment: Ian Preston from your example, I want to see all the product number abc-234, abc-570, ght-908 in the report but I want to see the ght-908 which is the last entered product number at the bottom of the row. so if i generate a report i should be able to add more product number and should be able to see all the previous product number as well but with the last product number at the bottom fo the row.Thanx guys for being patience.. hope this will make it more clear

Comment: Thank you all for the wonderful tips and ideas, I finally managed to get it done. I had to rewrite my store proc, which did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to order the results of the stored procedure by the order of the product codes as they are typed into the report parameter (which is a comma separated list).

You can return the index (order) of each product code in the parameter by using the Array.IndexOf and Split functions, e.g.

If you have a report parameter called "ProductNumber" and you also have a field called "ProductNumber" returned in your dataset, the following code will return the zero-based index of the Product Number as entered into the parameter list:

```
=Array.IndexOf(
     Split(Parameters!ProductNumber.Value.ToString(), ",")
   , Fields!ProductNumber.Value
 )
```

So if abc-234 is the first product number in the parameter list then this code will return 0. If abc-570 is the second product number in the parameter list then this code will return 1, etc.

Assuming the products are listed in a tablix, then I would set the tablix sort expression to the above, which should sort the products into the order specified in the report parameter.

[image]

Comment: I used your expression on sort but i didn't do nothing. I then used it on a text box it didnt do nothing either.My product number is a group. IF i use a =Join(Parameter!Product_Number,",") in a box then the box shows the product Number as ( the way I want to) so is there a way to sort the Product_Number based on the text box which shows the right order of the product number.? Thank you Nathan.

Comment: So you have a tablix, which contains a group and the group expression is something like "Fields!ProductNumber.Value"? If so then you should be able to use the above expression (subsitituting the field and parameter names that you are using) as the *sort* expression for the *group*. This assumes that the field in the dataset is returning exactly the same values as used in the parameter, without trailing spaces etc.

Comment: Thank you all for the wonderful tips and ideas, I finally managed to get it done. I had to rewrite my store proc, which did the trick.